# Matrix multiplication using matrix template library (MTL 2)

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra

Kindly give me some hint of matrix multiplication using MTL 2. Or any ref. or link for the documentation of MTL 2.

Comment: here is a complete example: http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mtl/show_src.php3?file=./examples/general_matvec_mult.cc

Comment: Thanks Beh, but this code is not running. Is we have to include some additional header file?

Comment: You need all the included files in a directory called mtl beside the cc file. Or else put them somewhere else and change the paths in the includes.

Comment: Oh, and that example has a typo. There is an include directive without a file named. Take that line out.

Comment: Well I have got the solution, http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mtl/show_src.php3?file=./examples/general_matvec_mult.cc working good after including math.h. Thanks all. But this code is not for matrix multiplication, this code is for the rotation of vector.

Comment: @Arman: I think you are expected to be able to figure out how to do the matrix multiplication yourself.  Following the example you have been shown it looks straightforward to modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're not supposed to post just links, but here you go. There is a choice of documentation in the sidebar of that page.

http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mtl/

Comment: Why not links? I prefer them. [edit] a link to an example would be better. http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mtl/show_src.php3?file=./examples/general_matvec_mult.cc

Comment: Thanks Kenny, but this code is not running. Is we have to include some additional header file?

Comment: There's a lot of back and forth on meta.stackoverflow.com about it. Lots of people think it's unfair to gain rep for something so trivial. It's kind of a flame-bait issue.